Bayesian estimation and biased estimators
I just learned nonBayesian vs Bayesian parameter estimation. My own summary:
nonBayesian: When statistics of a parameter are unavailable, CRLB holds for unbiased estimators, but there is a case in which a biased estimator outperforms unbiased ones.
Bayesian: MMSE is the conditional mean, which is always unbiased. Also Bayesian CRLB holds for unbiased estimators. Hence, biased estimators always satisfy the Bayesian CRLB and underperform MMSE, unbiased one.
Two questions:
Can anyone confirm the above my understanding?
Is there a good motivating example for biased estimators in the Bayesian estimation problems?
